# getChildAt(pos) returns null on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView where i have number of rows, each row has progress bar which updates.First four rows are visible.When row count is greater than 4 and i call getChildAt(pos) on my recyclerview to get the View,it is returning null. Kindly help.

Comment: Why does this surprise you? And where is the code?

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: View itemPosition = recyclerView.getChildAt(pos);  itemPosition  is null,when i scroll down to the item greater than the first 4 visible rows

Comment: if (null != itemPosition) {
         Do progress update
        }

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As recyclerView.getChildAt(position) was giving me null in the above scenario, I finally solved using the lines below. It can be useful to people who run into similar scenarios.

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = (RecyclerView.ViewHolder)
recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
if (null != holder) {
   holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.xyz).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: null != holder or holder != null ?

Comment: @BiswasKhayargoli It's the same thing.

Comment: .thing same the It's ;)

Answer (score 6):

When there is more than one page of data in your recycler view and you're using `getChildAt()` method, it will throw a null pointer exception. This is because when the position is greater than the number of visible items on the display, `getChildAt()` won't work as it can only get to the view that is displayed on the screen.

Therefore, use `recyclerView.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(position)` to get the view at the given position.

Answer (score 2):

You can set tags for every item in your adapter:

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder,position);
    holder.yourView.setTag(yourTag);
}
```

Then you can use the following code in your activity:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)(findViewById(R.id.recycler));
View yourView=(View)(recyclerView.findViewWithTag(YourTag));
```

Comment: I need the view while i scroll down the recyclerview beyond the first four visible rows and not when i click on a view.So i need to fetch the view based on position i guess

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of doing so? Because, I really don't understand what you're trying to do here. Can you share some code in order to clarify your purpose?If you just need to fetch out a view, you can do that in various ways. Also consider that your `RecyclerView` recycles every single `ViewHolder`, and roughly speaking you deal with 7~8 `ViewHolder`s, the amount depends on screen size.

Comment: I have a screen called MyDownloads,where i am displaying contents using RecyclerView. Each row of RecyclerView contains a progressbar to show the progress while downloading.I have an interface from where i am maintaining different states like OnStart,onEnd,OnProgress. In OnProgress method i am first trying to get the View using recyclerView.getChildAt(position), the if the view is not null i am making Progressbar visible using that view and updating the progress.

Comment: Everything works fine as long as my position value is equal or less than the number of visible rows in the ReccyclerView. When i need to scroll down to say a particular row,recyclerview.getChildAt(position) say 6 returns me null, and as a result i am not able to make the progressbar visible in that row and update it